# mpi exit code 65

Tags: mpi

I am running mpirun on a new (to me) refurbished workstation with 20 processors.  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Occasionally it terminates with an exit code of 65 for no apparent reason.  There is nothing in the terminal or the application log to indicate a problem, and if I restart the job it runs fine.  Does anyone know what this exit code means?  Is this potentially a hardware problem?

Comment: `perror 65` says `OS error code  65:  Package not installed`.

Comment: Thanks - any idea what package might not be installed, since it does run - just stops intermittently?

Comment: Check the documentation that came with `mpirun`.

Comment: Ok, I found this on the mpi site and also checked the mpi.h file on my machine and it matched.  I have no idea what this means. MPI_T_ERR_PVAR_NO_STARTSTOP
                          65      Variable cannot be started or stopped.